# Is there a chart library similar to SoundCloud showing audio and comments?

Tags: html, charts, visualization, soundcloud

I am after a HTML5 chart library that works similar to SoundCloud.com:

[image]

1. Show audio recording
2. Show timestamped comments against recording.

Do you know of anything that works like this or similar to it?

Thank you for your reply.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use Waveforms.js for showing the waveform, but you'll have to implement the comment system by yourself.

More info [here](http://www.waveformjs.org/)